# 2 elements have the same index?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class TSTER {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>(7);
        test.add(1);
        test.add(1);
        test.add(1);
        test.add(1);
        test.add(1);
        test.add(1);
        test.add(1);
        for(int d:test)
        {   
            System.out.println(d);
            int x = test.indexOf(d);
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        System.out.println(test.size());
    }    


}
```

The output is 10 and so on. The size i 7 but it seems like every time I print the index its 0

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf` uses `Object#equals()` to compare objects. The result of boxing `1` uses `Integer.valueOf(1)`, which returns an integer that is `equal` to all of the other integers you boxed.

In addition, some implementations maintain an integer cache, which means that the same *instance* of Integer may be inserted into the list.

The method performs correctly in this case. If you do not want this behavior, use a counter variable or an object that does not compare equal to other objects.

Answer (score 1):

[`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) returns the index of the first occurence of the given element.
Since all your elements are equal, the first index, `0`, is always returned.

Answer (score 0):

All the nubmers in the list are equal. That's why indexOf always returns the index of the first element (since it's equal to all the other elements).

Answer (score 0):

[`indexOf(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-)

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list,

There's a `1` at index 0 of your `ArrayList`, so that's returned.